# iOS countdown depending on the time of day comapared to set times

Tags: ios, mobile

Before I state what I am trying to learn how to do, let me tell you I have a decent knowledge base on programming but the timers and date functions are a little confusing to me. Also, this is my first post on stackoverflow. Hoping for a lot more to come as this looks like a great learning/engaging community!

What I am trying to learn:

I would like to create set times for every day of the week and have a countdown depending on the actual time of day to the next set time in line. For example if I have a set time at 2pm and it is noon, the countdown would read 2:00:00 until it hits zero, then it would reset and countdown to the next set time in line.

I know of NSTimer and NSDate but I need a little assistance using/combing the two to compare days and time to the actual day and time at any given time.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you may have!

Comment: Write the task down in comments - no code. This will force you to define and the refine the way this is going to work without being distracted with unfamiliar code.

I made a start for you
// 1 Populate array with times (in order)
// 2 check if device time is less than next time in array (starting at 0)
// 3 if less than array object, calculate difference then ..
// 4 set timer with time difference and start countdown - else 
// 5 check next item in array by repeating above from point 2

When comments completed, aim to write code to satisfy each comment. Job done.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, thanks! I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

NSTimeInterval is your answer. It is in seconds, so you have to format it.

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:referenceDate];

int hours = (int)(interval / 3600);
int minutes = (int)(interval / 60) - (hours * 60);
double seconds = fmod(interval, 60.0);

NSString *countdown = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%05.2f", hours, minutes, seconds];
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for! So I could use NSDate to set constants for each time(s) of each day of the week I want. Where does the countdown recognize what time of day it is, to know which constant will be next? The more I think about it the more this sounds like a set alarm clock.  I will try out the NSTimeInterval and see what I figure out. Thanks for your help!